# xml parsing problem with c# linq to xml - Reference to undeclared entity

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing, dtd

tryin to parse an xml file gives me the following error 
**Reference to undeclared entity 'eacute'**

after I created a dtd file with all the entities that I found here http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html and I loaded it as follows

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"..\xhtml-lat1.ent");
XmlParserContext con = new XmlParserContext(null, null, "iti", null, null, s, "", "", XmlSpace.None);
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings, con);
```

the loading an xdocument

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

give me the following exception **'=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'.**

any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this error happens when the xml document is not well-formed.

One tip to find the error, open your xml document in Internet Explorer. If the xml document is not well-formed, Internet Explorer will not be able to load the entire document and will tell you where the error is located.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, the only place a semicolon matters in XML is in an entity encoding. I would check for an incomplete entity (maybe &eacute) or a special character in the document that should be encoded.